# handling new line in java

Tags: java

i have written this small code

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(my_query);
ResultSetMetaData md=rs.getMetaData();
int numColumns =md.getColumnCount();

for (int i=1; i<numColumns+1; i++) {
     String columnName = md.getColumnName(i);
     Final+=columnName;
}


while (rs.next()) {
     for (int i=1; i<numColumns+1; i++) {
          String  output=rs.getString(md.getColumnName(i));
          Final+=output;
     }     
}
```

here i want to add  tab space  in String columnName = md.getColumnName(i);

and new line after Final+=output;

I have tried `\n` `\t` and `newLine()` but nothing worked properly,

since i want to have the `Final` string with all the column_names Plus data into one variable `Final`.

I am able to get that easily into `Final` but the issue is that its all in one line so i need to add tab space(columnName) between column and line space (Final) between rows. Please suggest.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing worked properly'? Did it blow up the computer, or did it make the the font green?

Comment: Final is very confusing. Member and local variables in Java should start with lowercase letter. But if you try to name it "final" you'll see it's a reserved word. Try "result".

Answer (score 2):

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(my_query);
ResultSetMetaData md=rs.getMetaData();
int numColumns =md.getColumnCount();

String output = md.getColumnName(1);
for (int i=2; i<numColumns+1; i++) {
    output += " " + columnName;
}
output += "\n";

while (rs.next()) {
   output += rs.getString(md.getColumnName(1));
   for (int i=2; i<numColumns+1; i++) {
       output += " " + rs.getString(md.getColumnName(i));
   }
   output +=  "\n";
}
```

Or you could work with lists. Create a new list at the beginning of each line, add elemenents to it and then at the end of the line join them all with spaces, add a newline and append to `output`. It would be clearer and more general than my proposed solution.

Comment: The solution may be correct but this "String Final" is making by head explode :) Please fix.